# vue methods axios function can not set data or ruturn response ,ps:function was used in created

Tags: vuejs2, axios

this is my todolist.VUE created code

```
  created () { // 组件创建时调用
    this.getUserInfo()
    console.log(this.id)//console undefined
    if (this.id === null) {
      this.$router.go('/')
    }
    this.getTodoList()
  },
  data () {
    return {
      name: 'Molunerfinn',
      todos: '',
      activeName: 'first',
      list: '',
      count: 0,
      id: ''
    }
  },
```

this is the function in methods :

```
 getUserInfo () {
      const token = sessionStorage.getItem('my-token')
      if (token) {
        let obj = {
          access_token: token
        }
        this.$http.post('/verify/verify', obj) //axios
        .then((res) => {
          this.id = res.data.info.id //res.data.info.id can be consoled
        }, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            this.$router.go('/')
          }
        })
      } else if (!token) {
        this.$router.go('/')
      }
    },
```

res.data.info.id  is what i want ,it is correct, i try to return res.data.info.id , but undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of your getUserInfo method add
self = this;
and then use self instead of this in a such way:

```
   self.id = res.data.info.id //res.data.info.id can be consoled
```